# Unable to edit html file in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I created a new html file in WebStorm, but somehow the file is highlighted red. I am wondering what is going on with this as I can't seem to edit the file even - it acts as though I am using the left and right arrow button when I click on "delete".

If there is anything I can do to change this - Please help.

Small video clip that illustrates the issue: https://flic.kr/p/HumEn4

[image: html file highlighted in red]

Comment: For ref purposes: same on JetBrains forums: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000744444-HTML-file-is-higlighted

Comment: So .. you are trying to edit the file content and pressing `Del` key there (inside the file). it's  not about actual file deletion? Does pressing `Del` key works in another file? Do you use vim mode or stuff like that? What's the keymap used? Any other issues when trying to edit the file? The behaviour you described is very weird, not solid ideas on what it might be. But I definitely suggest to restart IDE if you have not tried it yet.

Comment: @LazyOne Yeah thanks for pointing that out, but I'm posting here cos I couldn't get a correct answer /fix from the forum.

Comment: Here is a short vid clip of what i meant to clarify: https://flic.kr/p/HumEn4

Comment: Does pressing `Del` key works in **another** file? Do you use vim mode or stuff like that? What's the keymap used? Any other issues when trying to edit the file? If you go to `Settings/Preferences | Keymap` -- there is a button next to search field -- it allows to search for actions by keys assigned. What do you see when you press `Del` there? What actions are reported?